# Why is the step-2 different in the 2 cases?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, boyer-moore

While applying *Boyer–Moore string search algorithm* to the string :

```
SSIMPLE EXAMPLE
```

with a pattern:

```
EXAMPLE
```

the algorithm flows as :

```
SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ---------------------(1)
EXAMPLE

SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ----------------------------(2)
      EXAMPLE

SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ----------------------------------(3)
        EXAMPLE
```

but when applying the same algorithm to the same string :

```
SSIMPLE EXAMPLE
```

but with a slightly different pattern : (replacing the first E with a T)

```
TXAMPLE
```

the algorithm flows as :

```
SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ------------------- (1)
TXAMPLE

SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ----------------------(2)
       TXAMPLE

SSIMPLE EXAMPLE ---------------------------(3)
        TXAMPLE
```

From the first example :
*In the second step,`E` is under `E`*

and in the second example :
*In the second step,`T` is not under `E` but under a space*

why is that ? What difference does the alphabets `T` and `E` make in the word `TXAMPLE` and `EXAMPLE` respectively ?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out what the algorithm does, and why? It is very straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EXAMPLE, the first and last characters are the same, so if you match the last character, then you know that the string has an E at that position. So when you try and shift EXAMPLE along, you have to assume that the E in that position matches the first E in example.

in TXAMPLE, the last character occurs only at the end of the string, so if you match the last character, then you can shift the string along so far that the next attempted match does not overlap at all with the first one, because E doesn't match anywhere except at the end of the string.

Comment: I doubt if I can be clearer than http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_Good_Suffix_Rule. Basically, if you know that the last character of EXAMPLE or TXAMPLE has matched the text, you know that the text has an E where the last character is. You can immediately work out that if you shift the pattern only one character, you will end up comparing an L with an E, and fail. So you can shift the pattern along further than that - with TXAMPLE you can shift the whole pattern, but with EXAMPLE you can only shift far enough to line up the first E of EXAMPLE.